# Getting a Stackoverflow error while sending the instance of Main Class to another class

Tags: java, swing, stack-overflow

I am a newbie programmer trying to build the HangMan Game.

So, I have a Main class (Main JFrame)  that instantiates different other panel classes. One such panel is `keyboardPanel` which is basically a panel with JButtons. I have a `checkwithKey()` method in the Main Class and I need to call that in the `keyboardPanel` class (for the `ActionListener` class of the JButtons). For that I made a `getInstance()` methods in MainClass and called it in the `keyboardPanel` class. When I execute it, I am getting the stackoverflow error.

Below is the code snippets of MainFrame class:

```
  //MainFrame class
  public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
  public KeyboardPanel keyboardPanel;
  private static MainFrame mf;

   private MainFrame(){
   keyboardPanel = KeyboardPanel.getInstance();
   add(keyboardPanel);      
   }     

  public static MainFrame getInstance(){
    if(mf==null){
        mf = new MainFrame();
        return mf;
    }
    else
        return mf;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MainFrame frame = MainFrame.getInstance();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
   protected void checkwithKey(char c){
      //Logic
     }

    }
```

Below is the code snippet of KeyboardPanel class

```
   //KeyboardPanel Class
   public class KeyboardPanel extends JPanel {
      private static KeyboardPanel kdP;
      private MainFrame mf = MainFrame.getInstance() ;

      public static KeyboardPanel getInstance(){
        if(kdP == null){
          kdP = new KeyboardPanel();
          return kdP;
          }
            else
              return kdP;
        }        

        private KeyboardPanel(){
         //JButton Code..

         }

    class KeyAction implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        char c = a.getActionCommand().charAt(0);
        mf.checkwithKey(c);  // I need to call the checkwithkey() from Mainclass here
        }
      }

   }
```

Can anyone help me with this?

StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Native Method)
at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.init(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(Unknown Source)
at hangman.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:119)
at hangman.MainFrame.getInstance(MainFrame.java:30)
at hangman.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:134)
at hangman.MainFrame.getInstance(MainFrame.java:30)
at hangman.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:134)
at hangman.MainFrame.getInstance(MainFrame.java:30)
at hangman.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:134)
at hangman.MainFrame.getInstance(MainFrame.java:30)
at hangman.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:134)
at hangman.MainFrame.getInstance(MainFrame.java:30)
at hangman.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:134)
at hangman.MainFrame.getInstance(MainFrame.java:30)
at hangman.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:134)
at hangman.MainFrame.getInstance(MainFrame.java:30)
at hangman.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:134)
at hangman.MainFrame.getInstance(MainFrame.java:30)
at hangman.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:134)
at hangman.MainFrame.getInstance(MainFrame.java:30)
at hangman.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:134)
at hangman.MainFrame.getInstance(MainFrame.java:30)
at hangman.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:134)
at hangman.MainFrame.getInstance(MainFrame.java:30)
at hangman.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:134)
at hangman.MainFrame.getInstance(MainFrame.java:30)
```

Comment: Add the stacktrace please

Answer (score 0):

```
1) MainFrame frame = MainFrame.getInstance();
2) keyboardPanel = KeyboardPanel.getInstance();
3) private MainFrame mf = MainFrame.getInstance();
```

In the row 3) the MainFrame is not instantiated yet. As a result

```
if(mf==null)
```

returns true. And then it is trying to be instantiated one more time. So the main problem is in the usage of your classes. Their chained during initialization phase.

I think there are reasons to use KeyboardPanel class as singleton.
It makes sense only with MainFrame.
Here is the shortest solution in your case:

```
//MainFrame class
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    public KeyboardPanel keyboardPanel;
    private static MainFrame mf;

    private MainFrame(){
        keyboardPanel = new KeyboardPanel(this);
        add(keyboardPanel);
    }

    public static MainFrame getInstance(){
        if(mf==null){
            mf = new MainFrame();
        }
        return mf;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainFrame frame = MainFrame.getInstance();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    protected void checkwithKey(char c){
        //Logic
    }

}


//KeyboardPanel Class
public class KeyboardPanel extends JPanel {

    public KeyboardPanel(MainFrame mf){
        this.mf = mf;
    }

    class KeyAction implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            char c = a.getActionCommand().charAt(0);
            mf.checkwithKey(c);  // I need to call the checkwithkey() from Mainclass here
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh I get it now....So can please you suggest me a better approach to call the main class method into the other class. And also thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: @ArCh3r why did you decide to make KeyboardPanel a singleton?

Comment: I had no reason for making that singleton. I was actually copy pasting the code from another panel I made which is a singleton. I will try removing the singleton for keyboard class.

Comment: @ArCh3r I already done it in my answer. Take a look. If it solved your problem, please mark this answer as the right one.

Comment: Hey I am still getting the same error. I copied the code and ran it separately but I am still getting the stackoverflow error. Did it work for you?

Comment: @ArCh3r Sorry, remove this line from Keyboard:
private MainFrame mf = MainFrame.getInstance();